# android: how to position SearchManager somewhere around 60dip from top?

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I have implemented android's searchmanager using onSearchRequested().  This works fine but it shows itself on top of the page. How can I adjust the layout to just around 60dip from top?

many thanks,

Comment: I dont think we can adjust the position of the searchmanager.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I adjust the layout to just around 60dip from top?

You can modify the firmware to do that, presumably. Otherwise, you have no control over way it is displayed.